# SAS: Export value labels to Excel

Tags: excel, sas

Is it possible to export value labels to Excel instead of data values?

While proc export's label option enables exporting variable labels, I do not know a way to export value labels. Any ideas?

Recoding the data values themselves appears to be the only solution to me so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just PRINT the data to the Excel sheet instead of EXPORTing it.  Formats are honored by PROC PRINT (or any other method of producing outputs).

```
ods excel file='myfile.xlsx';
proc print data=mydata ; run;
ods excel close;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards ods. That saved me a lot of complicating programming somewhere else, too.